# Object of class yii\jui\Dialog could not be converted to string

Tags: yii2

I am trying to use the Dialog widget provided by Yii2 default installation,but the application throws the following error:

**exception 'yii\base\ErrorException' with message 'Object of class yii\jui\Dialog could not be converted to string'**

Code:

`Dialog::begin([
    'id'=>'my-dialog',
    'clientOptions' => [
        'modal' => true,
    ],
]);
echo 'Dialog contents here...';
Dialog::end();`

If anyone of you have faced this issue , please help me out on this.

Thank You!

Comment: Can you show more of your view code?

Comment: Hey Alex,
I realized i had done a silly mistake of using "<?=" instead of "<?php" before `Dialog::begin()`.

Got it working.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In yii2. change: `<?=` to `<?php`

...hope this helps

Comment: @chethan Please accept the answer if it's working in order to help community.